# Redirect URL after showing notice page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using a TomCat server and need to transition to a new location. I am going to leave a TomCat instance on the old server temporarily in order to gracefully forward old links. I have found tuckey's url rewrite and it seems to work very well, except it doesn't display a message before forwarding.

My current solution is to put a "moved" notice at: `http://myserver:8080/` with an HTML redirect that will auto-forward after 5 seconds.

I will then use a urlrewrite rule for any direct links, like: `http://myserver:8080/browse/ISSUE-123` to forward to `http://mynewserver:8080/browse/ISSUE-123`. This works, but I would like to be able to show the user a message before forwarding them to the new location.

Any tips would be much appreciated. I think the current solution is "sufficient", but it could be better.

**EDIT**

I found a solution that I think will work, but I'm still open to feedback. I created a simple JSP page with a scriptlet that will take an argument (generated by the URL rewriter) to put an HTML redirect in a "This page has moved" template. This way the users will get forwarded to the right place, and will also see a message telling them to update their links.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since this is already in place I figured I would detail my answer, in case it will help someone in the future.

This solution took maybe 30 minutes to implement.

1. Download Tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/)
2. Download UrlReWrite (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)
3. Configure the urlrewrite.xml with my desired forward

   ```
    <urlrewrite>
     <rule>
          <from>/browse/(.*)</from>
          <to type="redirect">http://mynewserver:8080/browse/$1</to>
     </rule>
    </urlrewrite>
   ```

This will immediately forward them the new page. I found a decent way to show a page and then forward by creating a simple html page as a .jsp with a scriptlet inside:

```
 <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="5;url=http://mynewserver:8080/browse/<%= request.getParameter("requestedPage") %>">
```

Then I updated the urlrewrite.xml to the following:

```
 <urlrewrite>
     <rule>
        <from>/browse/(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/forward.jsp?requestedPage=$1</to>
     </rule>
 </urlrewrite>
```

This will pass the in the desired page to the "forward" screen, which has a meta redirect to then go to the same page on the new server while also telling the user about the server move.

Comment: I am aware that this is vulnerable to XSS, but I couldn't (quickly) get the `EscapeHtml()` to work. Because this is an intranet only site, I was not concerned about this as a security risk.